# Programmatically Change Bootstrap Checkbox Switch to OFF on success completion of AJAX script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, bootstrap-5

I have an HTML Form that contains a Bootstrap Checkbox Switch on an Employee screen. It hides the fields to change a password. When you click it, it reveals them. (Click it again and it hides them again.)

What I want to do is change it to "off" when the AJAX script that updates the Employee record in the database returns SUCCESS, so the user can see the save was finished.

I have this:

```
var formData = $("#employeeForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Employee/SaveEmployee",
  data: formData,
  success: function(result) {
    $("#PasswordChange").prop("checked", false);
    $("#PasswordChange").click();
    // Process the result of the AJAX call
    // For example, you can show a success message or redirect to another page
  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    // Handle the error
  }
});
```

But it is not working. I know the AJAX is working because the value in the database are changing.

```js
$('#PasswordChange').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).val(true);
    $("#hiddenFields").show();
  } else {
    $(this).val(false);
    $("#hiddenFields").hide();
  }
});

// mocking the ajax callback
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('now');
  $("#PasswordChange").prop("checked", false);
  $("#PasswordChange").click();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <p>Toggle the checkbox inside three seconds.</p>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="form-check  form-switch col-4 align-with-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="false" id="PasswordChange" name="PasswordChange">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="PasswordChange">Change Password</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Hidden Rows for changing password-->
  <div class="form-group row" id="hiddenFields" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
      <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-4">
          <label>Old Password</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <label>New Password</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <label>Reenter New Pwd</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" id="Password" name="Password" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" id="NPassword1" name="NPassword1" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" id="NPassword2" name="NPassword2" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row offset-md-3">
    <div class="col-4">
      <button class="button button-sel" id="savebutton" name="savebutton" type="submit">SAVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's some nullifying overlap in the two things you're doing in the ajax callback. The first sets the checkbox to off, but then the click trigger sets it back to true. Just do the click.

```js
$('#PasswordChange').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).val(true);
    $("#hiddenFields").show();
  } else {
    $(this).val(false);
    $("#hiddenFields").hide();
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  $("#PasswordChange").click();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <p>Toggle the checkbox inside three seconds.</p>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="form-check form-switch col-4 align-with-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="false" id="PasswordChange" name="PasswordChange">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="PasswordChange">Change Password</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Hidden Rows for changing password-->
  <div class="form-group row" id="hiddenFields" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
      <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-4">
          <label>Old Password</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <label>New Password</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <label>Reenter New Pwd</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" id="Password" name="Password" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" id="NPassword1" name="NPassword1" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" id="NPassword2" name="NPassword2" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row offset-md-3">
    <div class="col-4">
      <button class="button button-sel" id="savebutton" name="savebutton" type="submit">SAVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```